# jquery callback in while loop not working

Tags: jquery, callback

I am no jquery expert but i thought the following would work

```
var next = true;
while(count != data.length)
{
    if(next == true)
    {                   
        calcRoute(directionsService, data, count, function(){next = true;});
        count++;
        next=false;                 
    }                               
}
function calcRoute(service, data, count, callback)
{
     .....
     callback();
}
```

so i need to wait until the calcRoute has finished before calling it again and i thought something like this would work but i end up in an infinite loop. Any advice would be much appreciated

Comment: Check for any circular references in your `callback()` to `calcRoute()`

Comment: Are you using Deferred? https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Comment: Is anything in the `calcRoute()` function asynchronous? From the code you've shown there isn't so the callback is moot.

Comment: Try promise method in your callback.

Comment: the above while loop is inside an ajax response and all processes are carried out from that response, the calcRoute is very similar to this one https://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/working-around-8-waypoint-limit-in-google-maps-directions-api/

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the unnecessary callback (you only need callback if calcRoute itself is somehow asynchronous), the infinite loop is caused by the next=false that you have within the condition.  What's happening is:

1. Next is true, proceed to call function.
2. Count incremented.
3. Next is set to false.
4. Loop is checked -- count is still not equal to data.length, but next is false, so it just keeps on looping.  The count never increments, so it never exits, and next is never set to true, so it never tries the function again.

This function will do what you want if you get rid of the whole "next" boolean part, and eliminate the callback.  Because it's not asynchronous, the calcRoute function -- even if called in response to an ajax query -- will execute completely before it calls count++ and moves to the next step in the loop.  Try something like:

```
while(count != data.length)
{
    calcRoute(directionsService, data, count);
    count++;                            
}
function calcRoute(service, data, count)
{
     .....
}
```

This will eliminate the infinite loop caused by the boolean check, and it will complete calcRoute for each entry before incrementing the count and looping.

**Addition responding to the comment below**

Even if the function calcRoute itself calls an asynchronous function, that doesn't make calcRoute itself asynchronous.  calcRoute could, and would, complete and exit before the asynchronous function within it returned a response -- this would still mean that it would complete, return its flag, and then the rest of the code would execute in linear fashion.  The next=true function would still execute BEFORE the next=false that's set in the linear code, and you would still end up with your infinite loop.

To resolve this, you would need to either have the async function trigger the callback instead of calcRoute, or switch over to using a promise architecture instead of an explicit callback function, depending on what options are available to the asynchronous function that you're using.

Comment: Hi Rob thanks for the answer but calcRoute is asynchronous it makes calls to the google direction api, you can see a similar version of my function in the question comments, due to googles api limits I have to make sure I am calling this function one after the other to reduce the possibility of hitting the limits. Doing your way results in hitting he limit immediately

Comment: The function calcRoute itself is not asynchronous, though -- if it's calling something asynchronous WITHIN the function (which isn't posted here, so we can't see it), then it's the called async function that would need to trigger the callback event, not calcRoute itself, because calcRoute could exit before the async function within it completes.

Comment: Ahhh I get you thanks I will have a look at that, does that mean I can pass the callback function through multiple functions?

Comment: You can, yes, if the function you're calling supports it.